# Angular JS calender in format MM/dd/YYYY

Tags: angularjs

Actully I want to show a calender which is in format of MM/dd/YYYY. I am using angular datepicker for that. But my date format is not showing like I want, it is showing yy-mm-dd only. I have changed this with the one I wanted. But still it is not coming.

```
             app.directive("datepicker", function() {
                return {
                    restrict : "A",
                    require : "ngModel",
                    link : function(scope, elem, attrs, RestrictedPartyAddEditCtrl) {
                        var updateModel = function(dateText) {
                            scope.$apply(function() {
                                RestrictedPartyAddEditCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
                            });
                        };
                        var options = {
                            dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
                            //dateFormat : "mm-dd-yy",
                            onSelect : function(dateText) {
                                updateModel(dateText);
                            }
                        };
                        elem.datepicker(options);
                    }
                }
            });

             <input type="text" id="expdt" ng-init="restrictedPartyData.expirationDate"
             ng-model="restrictedPartyData.expirationDate" datepicker >
```

Please let me know if any changes necessary, I have tried other dateformat too. but it not working. I just want a calender which will show the format MM/dd/YYYY only.

Thank You

Comment: Try reading the documentation of angular UI bootstrap. They have given examples [Angular UI link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.3.3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   ng-bind-html="datevalue |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"
```